# How to make ember, rails and active_model_serializers execute one query on hasMany relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, has-many, active-model-serializers

I am using ember with rails and active_model_serializers.

Lets say I have a model called report and it has many statistics.  Lets say one report has 2000 statistics.  When I call:

```
report.get('statistics').then(statistics => {
  //Do something
});
```

I get 2000 separate api calls to statistics and 2000 separate selects from my db.

When I add `include:['statistics']` to the controller method like so:

```
def show
  render json: @report, include:['statistics']
end
```

I get the same issue.

I am not sure if there is something I have to do to the ReportSerializer.rb file to enable to one query as oppose to 2000 for the comments relationship.

In a rails only application a call to my association generates one query.  And while I realize ember is not rails, I figure I am missing something simple.

So, how do I make accessing the association on my model generate one api call and one query? Or at least minimize the amount of api calls and queries?

**Added Info**

All associated statistics are needed so an operation can be done on report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a way for ember data and my rails backend to produce one query and one api call to acquire associations of a model.  So I created another method in the report controller that only deals with sending the association.

```
def include_statistics
  render json: Report.find(params[:id]).statistics.to_json
end
```

And in my ember client I call the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/api/v1/reports/1/include_statistics'
}).then(points => {
    //Do something
});
```